# C# audio recording using winmm.dll native code

Tags: c#, audio, pinvoke, recording, native-code

Please let me know how could i record and save audio file to my hard drive by using c# code.
I already downloaded code from one of the technical web page.
That may be i don't know enough that it can support recording and saving function as well.
Please let me show you some of my downloaded Code so that you can give me any suggestion how should i do.

[WaveIn.CS]

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SoundViewer
{
internal class WaveInHelper
{
    public static void Try(int err)
    {
        if (err != WaveNative.MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            throw new Exception(err.ToString());
    }
}

public delegate void BufferDoneEventHandler(IntPtr data, int size);

internal class WaveInBuffer : IDisposable
{
    public WaveInBuffer NextBuffer;

    private AutoResetEvent m_RecordEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private IntPtr m_WaveIn;

    private WaveNative.WaveHdr m_Header;
    private byte[] m_HeaderData;
    private GCHandle m_HeaderHandle;
    private GCHandle m_HeaderDataHandle;

    private bool m_Recording;

    internal static void WaveInProc(IntPtr hdrvr, int uMsg, int dwUser, ref WaveNative.WaveHdr wavhdr, int dwParam2)
    {
        if (uMsg == WaveNative.MM_WIM_DATA)
        {
            try
            {
                GCHandle h = (GCHandle)wavhdr.dwUser;
                WaveInBuffer buf = (WaveInBuffer)h.Target;
                buf.OnCompleted();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public WaveInBuffer(IntPtr waveInHandle, int size)
    {
        m_WaveIn = waveInHandle;

        m_HeaderHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(m_Header, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        m_Header.dwUser = (IntPtr)GCHandle.Alloc(this);
        m_HeaderData = new byte[size];
        m_HeaderDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(m_HeaderData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        m_Header.lpData = m_HeaderDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        m_Header.dwBufferLength = size;
        WaveInHelper.Try(WaveNative.waveInPrepareHeader(m_WaveIn, ref m_Header, Marshal.SizeOf(m_Header)));
    }
    ~WaveInBuffer()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_Header.lpData != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            WaveNative.waveInUnprepareHeader(m_WaveIn, ref m_Header, Marshal.SizeOf(m_Header));
            m_HeaderHandle.Free();
            m_Header.lpData = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        m_RecordEvent.Close();
        if (m_HeaderDataHandle.IsAllocated)
            m_HeaderDataHandle.Free();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public int Size
    {
        get { return m_Header.dwBufferLength; }
    }

    public IntPtr Data
    {
        get { return m_Header.lpData; }
    }

    public bool Record()
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            m_RecordEvent.Reset();                
            m_Recording = WaveNative.waveInAddBuffer(m_WaveIn, ref m_Header, Marshal.SizeOf(m_Header)) == WaveNative.MMSYSERR_NOERROR;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(string.Format("\n m_WaveIn: {0}, m_Header.dwBytesRecorded: {1}", m_WaveIn, m_Header.dwBytesRecorded));                
            //m_WaveIn.ToPointer();
            return m_Recording;
        }
    }

    public void WaitFor()
    {
        if (m_Recording)
            m_Recording = m_RecordEvent.WaitOne();
        else
            Thread.Sleep(0);
    }

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        m_RecordEvent.Set();
        m_Recording = false;
    }
}

public class WaveInRecorder : IDisposable
{
    private IntPtr m_WaveIn;
    private WaveInBuffer m_Buffers; // linked list
    private WaveInBuffer m_CurrentBuffer;
    private Thread m_Thread;
    private BufferDoneEventHandler m_DoneProc;
    private bool m_Finished;

    private WaveNative.WaveDelegate m_BufferProc = new WaveNative.WaveDelegate(WaveInBuffer.WaveInProc);

    public static int DeviceCount
    {
        get { return WaveNative.waveInGetNumDevs(); }
    }

    public WaveInRecorder(int device, WaveFormat format, int bufferSize, int bufferCount, BufferDoneEventHandler doneProc)
    {
        m_DoneProc = doneProc;
        WaveInHelper.Try(WaveNative.waveInOpen(out m_WaveIn, device, format, m_BufferProc, 0, WaveNative.CALLBACK_FUNCTION));
        AllocateBuffers(bufferSize, bufferCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferCount; i++)
        {
            SelectNextBuffer();
            m_CurrentBuffer.Record();
        }
        WaveInHelper.Try(WaveNative.waveInStart(m_WaveIn));
        m_Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        m_Thread.Start();
    }

    public void Recording()
    {
        //int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(m_WaveIn);
        //byte[] rawdata = new byte[256 * 1024];
        ////Marshal.Copy(m_WaveIn, rawdata, 0, rawsize);
        ////System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("C:\\TempImage\\audio_{0}.wav", Guid.NewGuid()), rawdata );

        //Marshal.Copy(rawdata, 0, m_WaveIn, rawdata.Length);
        ////System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("C:\\TempImage\\audio_{0}.wav", Guid.NewGuid()), rawdata);

        ////Marshal.FreeHGlobal(m_WaveIn);

        //System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(

        //int elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Reading unmanaged memory:");
        //// Print the 10 elements of the C-style unmanagedArray
        //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        //{
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(m_WaveIn, i * elementSize));
        //}
    }

    ~WaveInRecorder()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_Thread != null)
            try
            {
                m_Finished = true;
                if (m_WaveIn != IntPtr.Zero)
                    WaveNative.waveInReset(m_WaveIn);
                WaitForAllBuffers();
                m_Thread.Join();
                m_DoneProc = null;
                FreeBuffers();
                if (m_WaveIn != IntPtr.Zero)
                    WaveNative.waveInClose(m_WaveIn);
            }
            finally
            {
                m_Thread = null;
                m_WaveIn = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void ThreadProc()
    {
        while (!m_Finished)
        {
            Advance();
            if (m_DoneProc != null && !m_Finished)
                m_DoneProc(m_CurrentBuffer.Data, m_CurrentBuffer.Size);
            m_CurrentBuffer.Record();
        }
    }
    private void AllocateBuffers(int bufferSize, int bufferCount)
    {
        FreeBuffers();
        if (bufferCount > 0)
        {
            m_Buffers = new WaveInBuffer(m_WaveIn, bufferSize);
            WaveInBuffer Prev = m_Buffers;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < bufferCount; i++)
                {
                    WaveInBuffer Buf = new WaveInBuffer(m_WaveIn, bufferSize);
                    Prev.NextBuffer = Buf;
                    Prev = Buf;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Prev.NextBuffer = m_Buffers;
            }
        }
    }
    private void FreeBuffers()
    {
        m_CurrentBuffer = null;
        if (m_Buffers != null)
        {
            WaveInBuffer First = m_Buffers;
            m_Buffers = null;

            WaveInBuffer Current = First;
            do
            {
                WaveInBuffer Next = Current.NextBuffer;
                Current.Dispose();
                Current = Next;
            } while(Current != First);
        }
    }
    private void Advance()
    {
        SelectNextBuffer();
        m_CurrentBuffer.WaitFor();
    }
    private void SelectNextBuffer()
    {
        m_CurrentBuffer = m_CurrentBuffer == null ? m_Buffers : m_CurrentBuffer.NextBuffer;
    }
    private void WaitForAllBuffers()
    {
        WaveInBuffer Buf = m_Buffers;
        while (Buf.NextBuffer != m_Buffers)
        {
            Buf.WaitFor();
            Buf = Buf.NextBuffer;
        }
    }
}
```

}

[WaveNative.cs]

```
internal class WaveNative
{
    // consts
    public const int MMSYSERR_NOERROR = 0; // no error

    public const int MM_WOM_OPEN = 0x3BB;
    public const int MM_WOM_CLOSE = 0x3BC;
    public const int MM_WOM_DONE = 0x3BD;

    public const int MM_WIM_OPEN = 0x3BE;
    public const int MM_WIM_CLOSE = 0x3BF;
    public const int MM_WIM_DATA = 0x3C0;

    public const int CALLBACK_FUNCTION = 0x00030000;    // dwCallback is a FARPROC 

    public const int TIME_MS = 0x0001;  // time in milliseconds 
    public const int TIME_SAMPLES = 0x0002;  // number of wave samples 
    public const int TIME_BYTES = 0x0004;  // current byte offset 

    // callbacks
    public delegate void WaveDelegate(IntPtr hdrvr, int uMsg, int dwUser, ref WaveHdr wavhdr, int dwParam2);

    // structs 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] public struct WaveHdr
    {
        public IntPtr lpData; // pointer to locked data buffer
        public int dwBufferLength; // length of data buffer
        public int dwBytesRecorded; // used for input only
        public IntPtr dwUser; // for client's use
        public int dwFlags; // assorted flags (see defines)
        public int dwLoops; // loop control counter
        public IntPtr lpNext; // PWaveHdr, reserved for driver
        public int reserved; // reserved for driver
    }

    private const string mmdll = "winmm.dll";

    // WaveOut calls
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutGetNumDevs();
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutPrepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveOut, ref WaveHdr lpWaveOutHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutUnprepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveOut, ref WaveHdr lpWaveOutHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutWrite(IntPtr hWaveOut, ref WaveHdr lpWaveOutHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutOpen(out IntPtr hWaveOut, int uDeviceID, WaveFormat lpFormat, WaveDelegate dwCallback, int dwInstance, int dwFlags);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutReset(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutClose(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutPause(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutRestart(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutGetPosition(IntPtr hWaveOut, out int lpInfo, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hWaveOut, int dwVolume);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hWaveOut, out int dwVolume);

    // WaveIn calls
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInGetNumDevs();
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInAddBuffer(IntPtr hwi, ref WaveHdr pwh, int cbwh);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInClose(IntPtr hwi);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInOpen(out IntPtr phwi, int uDeviceID, WaveFormat lpFormat, WaveDelegate dwCallback, int dwInstance, int dwFlags);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInPrepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveIn, ref WaveHdr lpWaveInHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInUnprepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveIn, ref WaveHdr lpWaveInHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInReset(IntPtr hwi);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInStart(IntPtr hwi);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInStop(IntPtr hwi);        
}
```

Comment: Use NAudio.  It has a sample app named RecordingDemo. http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant. I would like to know that NAudio project can support .net framework 2.0 because our current project is already developed with only .net framework 2.0. So i need to add audio recording function to existing project which is developed with only .net framework 2.0. I think NAudio project use .net WPF features. So i would like to know this Naduio project is compatible with .net framework 2.0 or not.

Comment: It doesn't use WPF, it's winmm.dll based.

Comment: if so, it is so good, thank again.

Comment: you may want to take a look at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/an-audio-recorder-using-winmm-dll/